# How to access an apache server from a device behind the same router?

Tags: apache-2.2, livebox

I installed an Apache server on a computer and set a static ip to this computer.
Now I would like to access my server from another device behind the same router (Livebox).

How can I do that? It seems I must do some port forwarding, but I don't know how to configure it: I have 'from port', 'to port', 'protocol' and 'ip address'. I guess 'ip address' should be the static ip of my server, but what about the ports? And what url should I use to access the server from behind the router?

Comment: Behind the same router? Just connect to http://xx.xx.xx.xx where those xx's are replaced with the IP address of the server where you installed apache.

Answer (score 0):

Different router has different configurations. That you can figure out by visiting the manufacturer's user manual for the product. Usually it has a web GUI running at the device ip. You should.

- Web server should have static IP configured
- Forward the web server listening port, usually it is port 80 and 443
- Forward from router WAN IP to web server static IP(usually it is not required to enter WAN IP)
- Forward protocol is TCP

Comment: I think when 'jul' says "behind the same router" he/she means on the same LAN/subnet - in which case port-forwarding / routing is not an issue